# The Incredible Shrinking ELU Banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images, top-bar

Something awful has happened to the top of all our pages. Earlier today they looked like this:

[image: old page header]

But now it has shrunk to a nearly unreadable proportion:

[image: new page header]

The new version is completely shrunken, which also destroys the stroke width in the logo with the now-misshapen small caps.

It’s also grossly off-centered compared with the list beneath it: Questions / Tags / Users / Badges / Unanswered / Ask Question

And here you can see that the letters are randomly assembled! Look how the E and the N don't share the same base line:

[image: meta bar]

In fact, the G is floating down in comparison with the E, and the N is floating up. There's also something wrong with the S. Here you can see the weird hovering effects better, as well the bad keming between the N and the G, something which shouldn’t even be possible with proper letterspacing of the font’s small caps:

[image: just the English]
[image: just the Language]
[image: just the Usage]

Did someone try to hand-set small caps as images instead of letting the builtin letterspacing rules in the font for those handle everything?

If you look at the baseline on the first bullet of true small caps below, completely uniform and with correct letterfit between them (no bad keming here!), you’ll see how things ***should*** be:

[image: small cap demo]

Comment: The meta banner looks atrocious too - x-height is all messed up.

Comment: @curiousdannii Many letters are also randomly floating above or below a uniform baseline. Scary.

Comment: Again, this is a work in progress asset that y'all weren't meant to see.

Comment: I'm going to wait until the end of Thursday, if no one from the design team fixes the site's banner, I'm letting rip on Meta, and I'll include [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/tex-new-site-theme-is-live) (whose original main page was stunningly beautiful, just breathtaking)  and [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live). This has been a PR, and re-design disaster.  We're blending, we're all starting to look alike. How do you foster loyalty and affection if the websites look bare, cheap and BORING?!?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Trust me, I feel as you do. Please remember that the people with the power to do anything here, the ones we need to convince, are unlikely to be persuaded by angry attacks. Is anyone?

Answer (score 7):

This is a file path issue that's happening unintentionally while we prepare new theming assets. It'll be taken care of first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us so quickly.

Comment: Our new stuff isn't supposed to leak into the old stuff, my bad :) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You also have floating letters hovering both above and below the base line: see latest images from meta.

Comment: Yep, I know. These will be fixed tomorrow. :)

Comment: The banner is, relatively speaking, tiny. It's barely larger than the description on the search bar. Why is that?

Comment: Is it tomorrow yet? :)

Comment: Hip, hip, hoorah! The fat banner is back

Comment: @AaronShekey I hope you had a chance to read my comments/compliments before they were deleted.

Comment: Why did you mark this fixed when the new beta stuff still has [a completely mis-typeset ransom-note on meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4UbC.png)?

Comment: You can't blame that despicable kerning, x-height variation, or wobbly baseline on a file path issue. Sure the resource wasn't supposed to leak through to the old theme, but it should not be a thing in the new theme either (which I'm now seeing because I have beta themes turned on). It looks terrible. Make it stop, _pleeeeease_.

Comment: I want to retract my upvote. I thought that itty bitty banner was a mishap, a bizarre mistake instead, it was a foreshadowing of the future design. Horrible, horrible  design. How long did it take the team to strip away every single bit of EL&U's identity? 30 minutes? Now we're left with a shrunken ampersand and engorged mutant [French lilies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur-de-lis)